# Добавление MaterialTapTargetPrompt в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Какой код использовать для внедрения [этой либы](https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt) в Fragment?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ̶g̶e̶t̶A̶c̶t̶i̶v̶i̶t̶y̶(̶)̶

Comment: А подробнее как?